# How to set the GRAILS_HOME environment variable to the location where you extracted the zip?

Tags: grails, netbeans-7

It says go to My Computer/Advanced/Environment Variables to set it up.
But there is no Grails_Home there, should i create a new variable?

Then add the bin directory to your PATH variable: HOW? i only have 1 path variable and it shows to a different path.

help please :)     I HAVE NETBEANS 7.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This is all you have to do to get grails up and running on netbeans.

[higher res image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oXdw.png)

Comment: This doesnt seem to work in netbeans 9. When you click on tools menu, you get a drop down, not the dialog above. The dropdown seems to be missing any way to get to this options tab

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the directory where Grails_Home is to the path by adding it to the path variable. Just put it at the end of whatever is already there and separate with a semicolon. There is a fairly useful [tool](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Path-Editor.shtml) for doing it more easily.

Comment: can you write step by step how to do this, i have Win 7 ?